# Error when using C++11 List Initialization Syntax g++ compiler

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

When I use list initialization to init my class members, the complier complains it's a function.

The g++ output:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o main 
In file included from main.cpp:1:
./Cat.h:9:9: error: function definition does not declare parameters
    int age{};
        ^
...
```

compiler version:

```
$ g++ -v            
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

source doe, Cat.h:

```cpp
...
class Cat {
private:
    int age{};
    std::string name{};
public:
    Cat(int age, std::string name) : age(age), name(std::move(name)) {
        std::cout << "Cat: Constructor with two parameter is called" << std::endl;
    }
...
};
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "Cat.h"

Cat getCat() {
    Cat cat{1, "Kitty"};
    return cat;
}

int main() {
    Cat cat = getCat();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to compile with `g++ --std=c++11` (or 14 or 17)

Answer (score 0):

### Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Cat {
private:
    int age{};
    std::string name{};
public:
    Cat(int age, std::string name) : age(age), name(std::move(name)) {
        std::cout << "Cat: Constructor with two parameter is called" << std::endl;
    }
};

Cat getCat() {
    Cat cat{1, "Kitty"};
    return cat;
}

int main()
{
    auto cat = getCat();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `--std=c++17`

```
/work/so/scratch/src/p0.cpp:8:9: warning: private field 'age'
      is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
    int age{};
        ^
1 warning generated.
```

Compiled without `--std=c++17`

```
/work/so/scratch/src/p0.cpp:8:9: error: function definition
      does not declare parameters
    int age{};
        ^
/work/so/scratch/src/p0.cpp:9:17: error: function definition
      does not declare parameters
    std::string name{};
...
```